# Kafka Streams Fault-tolerance understanding

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Say, I have following :-

- Single Topic with 20 Partitions.
- I have 10 separate instances powering to streams-app(which are consuming from aforesaid topic) And on each Stream-app in configuration, I have added NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG=5.

Are following understanding correct ?

- Then I can have in total 50(10 * 5) logical tasks possible at MAX, but since no of partitions are 20, only 20 Tasks shall be spinned up !!

Also, since partition assignment to Stream-task is even, Would each partition be assigned to each of 20 tasks i.e. Each task gets to work upon a single partition ?

Is it correct going so far ?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It seems like your understanding is correct. Do you have a question or are you just looking for confirmation?

Comment: Hey Carlson, Yeah, I am looking for some expert in this field, to confirm this !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as there are 20 partitions, there cannot be more than 20 Kafka consumer tasks.

Since you have configured 50 tasks max across 10 instances, it cannot be guaranteed which instances will start the tasks. It could at worst end up as having 4 instances with 5 tasks each or best as 10 instances with 2 tasks each.

Comment: Are you sure about this @kazzaki ?? Does Kafka would not fo the Load-Balancing internally and assign the 2 partitions per active stream-task , being spread on 10 machines ?? So, there shall be 2 tasks being active on each of 10 instances !!!

Comment: Yes.. though where it will end up depends on a lots of factors/configs. 

You can read more details of the consumer rebalance protocol here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yvDmglryHM&feature=push-lsb&attr_tag=KjcpN5xTkrR9kpVS%3A6&ab_channel=ICZ-Channel1
Fine tuning the consumer and kaka configurations is the key to increase changes to meet the sweet spot of 10x2.

Comment: Actually, KafkaStreams is aware of instances and threads per instance. And it will assign tasks across instances (based on their capacity, ie, number of threads). Because all your instanced have the same number of threads, you can expect that each instance will get the same number of tasks assigned. (Typo in answer? -> `have configured 50 tasks` -> should be `50 threads` I guess)?